# Accept/trigger image keyboard (GIFs) with HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, gif, html-input

How we accept/trigger **image keyboard** (like GIF keyboard on Androids) with normal text input?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text">
```

[image: Accept/trigger image keyboard (GIFs) with HTML/JS]

When I try to insert a gif so I get

> ***Can't enter this content here.***

So the question is how we can trigger user is inserting some GIF image?

like...

```
<input type="text" accept="..." oninput="...">
```

This is possible?

**Resource:** https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard

Comment: you cannot put an image in a text field. that would require a `<input type="file">` and an `<img>` tag to show it.you might get away with making a pseudo element

Comment: You need a `<textarea/>` or a [Content Editable Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) to mix text with images.

Comment: That would be up to a browser to implement such a thing. Have you ever met a website where it works?

Comment: @Kaiido No, never seen that ;)

Answer (score 1):

**we cannot use GIF keyboard in HTML** because for GIF keyboard we need some native code. but we can use on that javascript framework which supports mobile native side.

In **React Native (javascript mobile framework)** we can use [react-native-image-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-keyboard) package to get this keyboard android and ios

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. To get an image, you need to use `<input type='file'>`.

```js
function displayImg() {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    //call the filereader
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e)  {
        //create the img tag
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        //get the image
        image.src = e.target.result;
        //resize the image
        image.style.width = '100%';
        image.style.height = '100%';
        document.body.appendChild(image);
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<body>
      <input type=file name=filename id=file>
     <button type=button onclick='displayImg()'>Display</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. I asking for ```<input type="text">``` when pasting gif